# Branch.io initSession returns empty BranchUniversalObject JSON and BranchLinkProperties JSON

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to add a sharing feature to my existing app using Unity Branch SDK.

I created the short URL using the following code.

```
BranchUniversalObject universalObject = new BranchUniversalObject();
BranchLinkProperties linkProperties = new BranchLinkProperties();
string deviceUniqueIdentifier = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;

universalObject.canonicalIdentifier = $"xLeague/{deviceUniqueIdentifier}";
universalObject.canonicalUrl = "http://xleague.games/";
universalObject.title = MetaDataManager.Title;
universalObject.contentDescription = MetaDataManager.Description;
universalObject.imageUrl = MetaDataManager.Image;

linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$desktop_url", "http://xleague.games/xleague-solitaire-share/");
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$android_url", "http://xleague.games/android");
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$ios_url", "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xleague-solitaire/id1480117114");
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$ipad_url", "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xleague-solitaire/id1480117114");
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$match_duration", "2000");
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$og_title", MetaDataManager.Title);
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$og_description", MetaDataManager.Description);
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$og_image_url", MetaDataManager.Image);
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$deviceID", deviceUniqueIdentifier);

Branch.getShortURL(universalObject, linkProperties, (param, error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Branch.getShortURL failed: " + error);
    }
    else if (param != null)
    {
        callback(param);
    }
});
```

I can get the following short URLs from Unity Branch.

https://xleague.app.link/r7DxT2wkZ5

https://xleague.app.link/4WPwY7jm05

https://xleague.app.link/LFfAOZuo05

https://xleague.app.link/hVR3fr0n05

And I retrieve BranchUniversalObject and BranchLinkProperties using the following code.

```
void Start()
{
    Branch.initSession(CallbackWithBranchUniversalObject);
}

void CallbackWithBranchUniversalObject(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties linkProps, string error)
{
    if (error != null)
        Debug.Log($"Error : {error}");
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(buo.ToJsonString());
        Debug.Log(linkProps.ToJsonString());
        if (linkProps.controlParams.ContainsKey("$deviceID"))
        {
            string senderDeviceID = linkProps.controlParams["$deviceID"];
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I click the shared link on iPhone or Android, it will redirect me to Appstore or Google Play Store. I can install the app on the Appstore and Google Play Store.
But when I opened the app, initSession returns empty BranchUniversalObject JSON and BranchLinkProperties JSON.

BranchUniversalObject JSON

```
{
  "$canonical_identifier": "",
  "$canonical_url": "",
  "$og_title": "",
  "$og_description": "",
  "$og_image_url": "",
  "$publicly_indexable": "0",
  "$locally_indexable": "0",
  "$exp_date": "69425078400000",
  "$keywords": [],
  "metadata": "{}"
}
```

BranchLinkProperties JSON

```
{
  "~tags": [],
  "~feature": "",
  "~alias": "",
  "~channel": "",
  "~stage": "",
  "~duration": "0",
  "control_params": {}
}
```

What makes me more confused is that initSession sometimes returns correct BranchUniversalObject JSON and BranchLinkProperties JSON as expected. I guess the Branch Short URL that I created only works for the first click.
I'd be much appreciated you if you could help me.

Comment: Can you share which version of SDK are you on? Also please share you Manifext.xml file and if you are seeing this behaviour in Live Mode or Test Mode

Comment: The Branch SDK version is 0.6.5.

Comment: Manifest.xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ACDzy6f-F62iPFs-jsKr6reYXu2Ey-48/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw this behavior in Live Mode.

Comment: Do you see any error or any other logs in the cases where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster Here -

Please double check your integration as mentioned [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/unity). For further troubleshooting you can also follow as mentioned [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/unity#section-troubleshooting-issues). If this is happening when you click a link from background please make sure that you are following the [intra-app linking](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-advanced-features#section-handle-links-in-your-own-app) guidelines and make sure onNewIntent is implemented as [recommended](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration#section-initialize-branch).

Please note thaT when a link is clicked, it should only open the Activity which has the initSession() method. Also please don't share your Branch Keys publicly.